# UITableView cell just disappeared callback?

Tags: ios

I have a UITableView with heavy images content. So the scrolling is not fluid anymore.
I want to add a timer to load the images, while you scroll I create the timer for each row. If the cell quits the view, I cancel the timer. If not I fade in the images.

My question is : is there a callback for a cell going out of view ? I'm reading the doc, but I'm not sure there is anything for my needs.

Thanks for the help !

EDIT: The code I'm using (this is the three20 library, I'm using a custom TTTableItemCell. The "_tabBar1.tabItems = item.photos" is the line hoging resources. On the first load it's okay because the photos are being loaded asynchronously from the server, but when I scroll back or reload the view, they are all loaded synchronously, and the scrolling isn't smooth anymore, especially on an iPhone 3G. :

```
- (void)setObject:(id)object {
    if (_item != object) {
        [super setObject:object];

        Mission* item = object;

        self.textLabel.text = item.name;
        _tabBar1.tabItems = nil;

        timerFeats = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.5f) target:self selector:@selector(updateFeats) userInfo:nil repeats: NO];  
        //_tabBar1.tabItems = item.photos;
  }
}

-(void)updateFeats {
    DLog(@"timer ended");
    Mission* item = self.object;
    self._tabBar1.tabItems = item.photos;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I found a way.

There is actually a callback to know what cell is about to get out of view. :

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview;
```

So my code is :

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview {
    [super willMoveToSuperview:newSuperview];
    if(!newSuperview) {
        DLog(@"timer invalidated");
        if ([timerFeats isValid]) {
          [timerFeats invalidate];
        }

    }
}
```

If there is no newSuperview the cell is going out of the view and so I verify first that my timer hasn't been invalidated yet, and then I cancel it.

Comment: This seems to fire for as soon as a cell comes *in* to view

Comment: @Matt as of iOS 7.02 this method might not be called at all when you scroll out a cell and scroll it back in. But as soon at it get's visible again the prepareForReuse method is called. During the time that it is not visible only the hidden flag is TRUE, but it is still attached to the tableview. So there's no change of the superview.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using iOS 6 and up, simply override this method:

`- tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

It'll be called when the cell has already gone out of the view, and you'll get it and its indexPath.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a KVO approach:

On your awakeFromNib method (or whatever method you use to instantiate the cell) add the following:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"hidden" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    ...
}
```

Be sure to implement the delegate method for the observer as follow:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"hidden"]) {
        NSLog(@"cell is hidden");
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I only get notified when the cell turns visible again. The KVO is not triggered when the system sets hidden to TRUE. I also tried overriding setHidden: , but this is also not called when transitioning to hidden = TRUE;

Answer (score 0):

When a `UITableView` is initially shown it calls this method once for each row

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

after this the method is called when ever a new row is required which is often the result of scrolling to reveal a new row and pushing an old view off the other end.

So this is an ideal hook to find out which rows are visible. To check which cells are visible you can call

```
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

Because the tableview is the only thing holding a reference to your cells before they are recycled or freshly creaetd you can not get a handle on those timers. What I suggest is creating an `NSMutableDictionary` ivar and when you create your cells add the timer to the `NSMutableDictionary`

```
[timersForIndexs setObject:yourTimer forKey:indexPath];
```

Now when you recieve `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you need to do something like

```
 NSMutableDictionary *tmpDictionary = [timersForIndexs copy];

 [tmpDictionary removeObjectsForKeys:[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]];

 NSArray *timers = [tmpDictionary allKeys];

 [timers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(invalidate)];
```

I'm not in front of xcode so this is dry coded so please let me know if you have any problems

Comment: I'm trying that but apparently, if I use [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexToRemove] on a cell that's not visible I get a null, so I can't cancel my timer.

Comment: I do get the array of the visible rows, the problem is that I can only access these rows with the method cellForRowAtIndexPath. Any other row give me a (null). Which I guess is because the cell has be dequeued ?

Comment: Then can we see the code that is taking a long time and maybe we can suggest something you could do

Comment: Sorry I don't know about the three20 framework so I cant help you with that.

Comment: Well the TTTableView is only a subclass of the UITableView, so all your methods are working. The only issue I'm facing is that I don't know how the access the already running timers once the cell is out of view.